# Using on-board graphics with Nvidia graphics card

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I have recently installed a DH61WW Intel board. It came with Intel HD Graphics. I also have an Nvidia GT-220 graphics card.

I want to be able to use both the on-board and Nvidia GPU to maximize the performance.

Currently I have turned the integrated graphics to "Always Disabled" in the Bios, thus I use the Nvidia graphics card.

P.S. I am only using a single display.

Comment: it would be helpful to formulate a question...

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS if it has a setting for "Lucid Virtu" multi-graphics support?

Comment: If you want to maximize the performance then you only want to use the GTX card its capabilities is several times better then the Intel HD Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Using both the NVidia Card and Intel HD Graphics is only possible if it is supported by the BIOS which is generally the case in case of laptops and not desktops